# Book with Goya cover

Tags: story-identification, cover-art

I remember seeing a book cover, possibly on a John Brunner book.
The cover featured “The Colossus’ a painting by Goya.
I didn’t see the actual book, but saw it as an entry in an encyclopaedia of SF - maybe in one of the ones attached as pictures.

- I think it was paperback, probably British edition.
- I guess published between 1970 and 1985.

[image: Encyclopedia of Science Fiction cover][image: The Visual Encyclopedia of Science Fiction cover]

Comment: For the record, The Colossus is [no longer attributed to Goya but to his assistant Asensio Juliá](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2009/jan/27/goya-colossus-spain-prado)

Comment: Goodreads suggests that neither of those books were ever published with that image as the cover shot; https://www.goodreads.com/work/editions/2184253-stand-on-zanzibar?page=2

Comment: @Valorum [The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Colossus_(painting)) on "The Colossus" addresses that controversy , and it appears that that reattribution is not widely accepted.

Comment: @Spencer - I'm reasonably happy to accept the word of the people who currently own it and display it.

Comment: Frankly, illustrating a story with Goya sounds more like something _Omni_ magazine would have done.

Comment: I’ve ordered the two encyclopaedias from eBay, so in a few weeks I’ll see if it’s my memory that’s wrong.

Comment: This probably isn't it because it isn't really Goya, but at least one cover for Brunner's "The Atlantic Abomination" is sort of Colossus-esque.

Comment: @Martin It's been a few weeks, a year even. Any new input? :)

Comment: Nope. Got the encyclopaedias, and more besides. No joy.